# Why my answer was deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I answered the question: [Is there a way to completely wipe out iPhone data programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195941/is-there-a-way-to-completely-wipe-out-iphone-data-programatically)

Here is my answer: [Is there a way to completely wipe out iPhone data programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195941/is-there-a-way-to-completely-wipe-out-iphone-data-programatically/15205856#15205856)

Please can somebody explain, what is the problem with it?  I would appreciate, if it will be undeleted and I can modify it to make acceptable.

The text of answer is following:

> There is a private API SBDataReset in SpringboardServices private framework. It wipes all data.
>
> You can check [following code](https://github.com/lite/osxrce/blob/master/resetapp/main.m) for example how to use it.
>
> Application which uses this API should have "com.apple.springboard.wipedevice" entitlement to work.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. It doesn't fully answer the question, but instead puts part of the answer behind a link.  It would be better to show the example that answers the question that was asked.
2. It's nearly an exact duplicate of [this other answer by you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15205830/1288).  If those two questions are duplicates, please flag one of them or vote to close instead of copy/pasting the same answer.  If they're not duplicates, then customize your answers so each one answers the particular question being asked.

Comment: This is the answer. I deleted it, and these are the exact reasons why.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Thank you. I wasn't aware of (2).