# Should "exact duplicates of other answers" in faq be more descriptive?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, faq-update-request

This [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) includes a text:

"exact duplicates of other answers"

I believe it would nice to add there some explanation that it both applicable to duplicating somebody else answer and your own answer.

It [wasn't obvious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170126/why-my-answer-was-deleted-by-a-moderator) for me (after a year on SO and 4K+ reputation)

Comment: Yeah, I agree! I only learnt it a few weeks ago, after closely a year on SO.

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps a very short addition such as *(including your own posts)*

Comment: Why would one person answer a question with two duplicate answers? Not saying a short blurb would hurt, but how often does this actually happen?

Comment: @Geobits: Actually, it's not about answering the same question with two duplicate answers, but rather answering two similar/duplicate questions with the two exactly same answers.

Comment: Ah, I misread his other post. That I can see happening often enough ;)

Comment: I wonder why the old post is being closed as the duplicate of the new post!

Comment: @Siva Sometimes the highest-quality post (including the answers in that evaluation) are considered the 'canonical' (or 'original') post for purposes of closing as a dupe.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Thanks. Good to know. I always try to mark the new posts as the dupes of the old ones. In this case, both the posts were by the same user. A scenario that I have come across quite often in the past few days.